# Can I get rid of the Mickey Mouse glove?

Tags: macos, mouse, cursor

The cursor changes to a mickey mouse glove when hovering over links. I'm coming from the Linux world and there doesn't seem to be an option in the settings that can change it, it is driving me insane. Wondering if there is a 3rd party app or hidden setting that affects it. Thanks.

Comment: It's not a Mickey Mouse glove because if it was Apple would have to pay a royalty to Disney if it was. Mickey Mouse's hand is drawn with 3 fingers and a thumb and the link cursor is drawn with 4 fingers and thumb.

Answer (score 1):

[Mousecape](https://github.com/alexzielenski/Mousecape/releases) may be the answer for you. It has not been updated since last July (though notes from February 2014 claim compatibility with Yosemite...not sure how that's possible) so YMMV, but it may be worth a shot.

On the page linked above, make sure you click on 0.0.5 and NOT "cursor flip". Clicking on cursor flip will download a related program that is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can select a personal stylesheet in the perefences in Safari. This way you could change the cursor for links to whatever you like. Make a file called style.css witht the following content. In Safari go to Preferences->Advanced and select the stylesheet.

```
a {
    cursor:default !important;
}
```

I'm pretty sure that other browsers have the same option.